# I am getting a 404 not found Error in Spring Application

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am not able to navigate to the next page search can you please tell me what am I doing wrong here.I am getting a 404 not found Error.

I am trying to assemble a code found in https://github.com/christophstrobl/spring-data-solr-showcase

SearchController.java

```
/*
 * Copyright 2012 - 2013 the original author or authors.
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 * http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */
package org.springframework.data.solr.showcase.product.web;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.LinkedHashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;
import org.springframework.data.solr.core.query.result.FacetFieldEntry;
import org.springframework.data.solr.core.query.result.FacetPage;
import org.springframework.data.solr.showcase.product.ProductService;
import org.springframework.data.solr.showcase.product.model.Product;
import org.springframework.data.web.PageableDefault;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.util.StringUtils;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;


@Path("/")
@Controller
@Component
@Scope("prototype")
public class SearchController {

    private ProductService productService;

    @RequestMapping("/search")
    public String search(Model model, @RequestParam(value = "q", required = false) String query, @PageableDefault(
            page = 0, size = ProductService.DEFAULT_PAGE_SIZE) Pageable pageable, HttpServletRequest request) {

        model.addAttribute("page", productService.findByName(query, pageable));
        model.addAttribute("pageable", pageable);
        model.addAttribute("query", query);
        return "search";
    }

    @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(value = "/autocomplete", produces = "application/json")
    public Set<String> autoComplete(Model model, @RequestParam("term") String query,
            @PageableDefault(page = 0, size = 1) Pageable pageable) {
        if (!StringUtils.hasText(query)) {
            return Collections.emptySet();
        }

        FacetPage<Product> result = productService.autocompleteNameFragment(query, pageable);

        Set<String> titles = new LinkedHashSet<String>();
        for (Page<FacetFieldEntry> page : result.getFacetResultPages()) {
            for (FacetFieldEntry entry : page) {
                if (entry.getValue().contains(query)) { // we have to do this as we do not use terms vector or a string field
                    titles.add(entry.getValue());
                }
            }
        }
        return titles;
    }

    @Autowired
    public void setProductService(ProductService productService) {
        this.productService = productService;
    }

}
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>Testing2</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

  <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
 </listener>

 <!-- applies log4j configuration -->
    <listener>
       <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>
    </listener>



   <servlet>
        <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>org.springframework.data.solr.showcase.product.web</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Index.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8" trimDirectiveWhitespaces="true"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ page session="false"%>
<html>
<head>
    <title>spring-data-solr-showcase</title>
    <link href="<c:url value="/resources/css/styles.css" />" rel="stylesheet"  type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<c:url value="/resources/jquery/jquery-1.8.2.js" />"></script>
</head>
<body>
    Welcome.<br />
    Search Sample &gt; <a href="./search">goto</a>
</body>
```

My applicationContext.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">
    <context:component-scan base-package="org.springframework.data.solr.showcase" />
</beans>
```

Comment: What's the url you are using for next page? For first page? What's the search term? What's the page size? Do you have more results than the  page size? For example if your search returns 5 results and your page size is 10 you cannot have a second page.

Comment: Show me your application-context.xml .

Comment: I am just clicking the go to link and I want to hit the SearchController's search method.My applicationContext.xml looks like this.

Comment: Now I am getting Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'solr.host' in string value "${solr.host}"